# Unity3D - Deserialize Json C# (JsonFx)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json-deserialization

I've tried other peoples solutions found online with JsonFX but I keep getting the same error.

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination
>   type.
>   Pathfinding.Serialization.JsonFx.JsonReader.Deserialize[Child[]]
>   (System.String value) GetData+c__Iterator2.MoveNext () (at
>   assets/GetData.cs:37)

I retrieve a JSON string from a webpage, (e.g. an array with 2 elements)

> [
>   {"id":"1","age":"1","teeth":"4","url":"http://hidden","father":"John","mother":"Jaime","childFk":"1"},{"id":"2","age":"2","teeth":"7","url":"http://hidden","father":"Zach","mother":"Briann","childFk":"1"}
>   ]

My code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Pathfinding.Serialization.JsonFx;

public class Child {

    public int id;
    public int age;
    public int teeth;
    public string url;
    public string father;
    public string mother;
    public int childFk;
}

public class GetData : MonoBehaviour {

    public string url = "https://hiddenPage";
    public Text exampleText;
    public string jsonString;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(getJSON());
    }

    IEnumerator getJSON() {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;

        jsonString = www.text;
        exampleText.text = jsonString;
        Debug.Log(jsonString);

        Child[] testData = JsonReader.Deserialize<Child[]>(jsonString); //LINE 37
        foreach(var row in testData){
            Debug.Log(row.father);
        }
        Debug.Log(testdata);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!! :-)

Comment: Nice. Make sure to search problem before posting. You never know if the answer is out there.